# Which languages allow to change identity of an object (not cast)?

Tags: oop, language-features, downcast

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5967914/11343), a brave wants (in C++) to downcast a object of type `Base` to a `Derived` type. Assuming that the Derived type has no more attributes than `Base`, it *can* make sense if you're jealous of the extra methods that the `Derived` class provides.

Are there programming languages that allow such a thing?

Comment: Methods is what defines classes, not attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is something that is done without problem in Common Lisp, and in other Lisp dialects where CLOS (Common Lis Object System) was ported. You use the [`change-class`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_chg_cl.htm) generic function for that.

CLOS works with multiple dispatch methods, so a method is not tied to a class or object, it's just a function that is chosen in a group of similar functions WRT to the types (or identities) of its arguments. When using `change-class`, you can give arguments as if you were creating a new instance, and data already stored in the object will remain. Here is a little session that shows how it works:

```
CL-USER> (defclass base ()
       ((name :initarg :name)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS BASE>
CL-USER> (defclass derived (base)
       ((age :initarg :age :initform 0)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS DERIVED>
CL-USER> (defvar foo (make-instance 'base :name "John Doe"))
FOO
CL-USER> (change-class foo 'derived :age 27)
#<DERIVED {100338F2D1}>
CL-USER> (with-slots (name age) foo
       (list name age))
("John Doe" 27)
CL-USER> (defvar bar (make-instance 'base :name "Baby Joe"))
BAR
CL-USER> (change-class bar 'derived)
#<DERIVED {10036CF6E1}>
CL-USER> (with-slots (name age) bar
       (list name age))
("Baby Joe" 0)
CL-USER>
```

If this default behaviour is not enough, you may define a method on [`update-instance-for-different-class`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_update.htm#update-instance-for-different-class).

So yeah, *there are programming languages that allow such a thing*!

Comment: If you want to see what Lisp is capable of, there are two incedible resources. If you want something more pragmatic, go for Practical Common Lisp from Peter Seibel (http://gigamonkeys.com/book/) and if you're at least a bit math-savvy and want to be deeply enlightened on the very nature of computer programming, try SICP (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/ and there are videos of the course http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/)

Answer (score 1):

No, but it's a strong code smell to do that in the first place.

A way better alternative is to use the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), this is exactly what it was made to do.

Comment: Don't answer "No" to a question when you want to say "I don't like it". Especially when "No" is factually wrong…

Answer (score 0):

If `Derived` adds no attributes then the method it adds must operate on state that it gets from `Base`. In that case, why not just move those methods to `Base` where they belong?

Comment: Exactly because of @Albus comment on the question. Attributes do not define the class, a class has different identity/functionality with different methods.

Comment: This is even the notion of type classes in Haskell. The same object can be in different type classes if it implements the functions of each class…