# What is the most suitable way to return base object to up-casted derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

```
struct B {};  // B contains data members
struct D : B {};  // D doesn't contain ANY data member

B g_b;  // global object
D& fun ()  // want to return by reference ONLY
{
  return <???>(g_b);  // how ???
}
```

[Note: I want to avoid overloading constructor (or assignment) such as `D(const B&)`.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is undefined behavior.
You can use `dynamic_cast` for performing safe down casting of Base class pointer/reference to derived class pointer/reference. It returns a null in case of pointers or throws an exception in case of references.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is illegal. `g_b` is not a `D`.

Comment: `g_b` you mean, but yes. It's an instance of `B` only, not `D`. There's no legal way to refer to it via a `D&`, because `D&` means "reference to an instance of D". Which it isn't :-)

Answer (score 2):

No suitable cast. That is in fact undefined behavior.

For detail, see this topic:  [Downcasting a base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967914/downcasting-a-base-type)

Note : the term is *downcast* when you cast base to derived class; and the term *upcast* is used when you cast derived to base class.

Comment: +1, notifying for upcast and downcast however, what I meant in the question was that, I am just receiving by base class ; the object is of known type (which is derived). That's why used upcasting.