# What does "subobject" mean in C++ standard when describing downcast using static_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, standards, undefined-behavior, static-cast

I've read the topic [Downcasting a base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967914/downcasting-a-base-type) and I'm still in doubts.

```
class Base 
{
    int i;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main()
{    
    Base* x = new Base();
    Derived* y = static_cast<Derived*>(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Do I understand right that even this code is already wrong and can cause undefined behavior?

I ask it because I can't fully understand the standard phrase:

> If the rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is
>   actually a subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer
>   points to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the result of the
>   cast is undefined.

The word "subobject" confuses me. Here pointer **x** points in reality just to integer **i**. But This integer can be considered as a Derived object, isn't it? Because any Deived object is also just an integer. And this integer is clearly a subobject of itself. And so here is no UB.

Or (if this reasoning is wrong) does this phrase imply then that we should always have somewhere a creation of a Derived object? So it should be like here, for example:

```
Derived* z = new Derived();
// ...
// And only if the actual creation of a Derived instance
// took place somewhere the below code is ok
Base* x = z;
Derived* y = static_cast<Derived*>(x);
```

Comment: Yes this implies the first code fragment is UB and the second is legal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18452260/1870760

Comment: Undefined behavior is really hard to predict. The code fragment you present here *might* work, or it might blow up in your face - and it doesn't need to be consistent.

Comment: Thank you,  @milleniumbug, I just really needed to check it for full understanding.